# React , svg spinner icon freezes when async calls firing

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I created a wrapper component in react for buttons on my app that adds a little svg loading spinner to a button when things are loading on my map to give a little feedback to the user. I am noticing on using mobile safari/chrome that the svg spinner tends to freeze up when I am firing multiple service calls, and am trying to figure out how to smooth this out.

So my button looks like so -

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.checkIfDisabled = this.checkIfDisabled.bind(this);
    this.renderButtonInner = this.renderButtonInner.bind(this);
  }

  checkIfDisabled() {
    if (this.props.isLoading) {
      return true;
    } else if (this.props.disabled === true) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  renderButtonInner() {
    if (this.props.isLoading) {
      return (
        <div>
          <span className="button-loader"></span> {this.props.children}
        </div>
      );
    }
    return this.props.children;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        className={`LoadingButton ${this.props.styleClasses}`}
        onClick={this.props.onClick}
        disabled={this.checkIfDisabled()}
        type={this.props.type || 'button' }
        >
        {this.renderButtonInner()}
      </button>
    );
  }
```

and the accompanying css (scss) :

```
 .LoadingButton {
  .button-loader {
    background: url(/images/icons/loading-button.svg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

And I have been using this component like so -

```
 <LoadingButton
      isLoading={bool to tell if button is in loading state}
      styleClasses="my custom classes here"
      onClick={click callback here}
      >
       Button!
  </LoadingButton>
```

It has been working great for desktop, but I am noticing on mobile that when async calls are fired to my backend, the spinner freezes up. I am not sure what else I should do to resolve this - maybe I shouldn't be using an svg as a background image? IS there a better approach to adding this spinner that might stop it from freezing? Thanks for reading!

Comment: Have you try to add this svg with a `<img>` tag inside your `<button>` ?

Comment: @Alexis no - i will give it a shot! what about that helps the freezing?

Comment: It's just an idea. I don't know what's the cause, but i can help you to find an other solution :-p

Comment: Is it freezing on all mobile browser or just only 1 ? Maybe the browser used is the cause

Comment: @Alexis mobile safari, mobile chrome on iphone 5 and 6, I am trying implementing the img as you suggested now. maybe a more direct reference will help.

Comment: Have you try ? What's the result ?